# Understanding SLQ syntax error in Flyway initial migration

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I am configuring Flyway for a brand new Spring Boot project. This is the initial migration provided by DBA.

The application works in SQL Server, however I am struggling to make it work on H2 for in-memory testing purposes. The DBA didn't provide (and maybe is not going to provide) a dialect-neutral version of the DDL.

I tried to use H2's SQL Server mode

application.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:almc-be;Mode=MSSQLServer


  flyway:
    check-location: true
    enabled: true
    encoding: utf-8
    locations: classpath:/flyway/${spring.datasource.platform:sqlserver}
    create-schemas: true
    default-schema: dbo
    schemas: dbo
```

Beginning of the script

```
-- Create tables section -------------------------------------------------

-- Table dbo.Users

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserId] Int NOT NULL,
    [UserName] Nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [UserSurname] Nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [UserEmail] Nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
go

-- Add keys for table dbo.Users
```

On startup, I get the following error

```
2021-07-22 15:48:43.189  WARN 6316 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V202107221432__DDL.sql failed
---------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ""dbo"".""Users""
(
    ""UserId"" INT NOT NULL,
    ""UserName"" NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ""UserSurname"" NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ""UserEmail"" NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
GO[*]

                               

ALTER TABLE ""dbo"".""Users"" ADD CONSTRAINT ""PK_Users"" PRIMARY KEY (""UserId"")
GO
```

Yes, the escape sequence is **changed** in the logs from the SQL file

What is the cause of the error and how can I fix it without rewriting the script into a dialect-neutral version myself?